# Calculated Column to based on three other columns

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

I have trouble making calculated columns, still learning.

I am trying to identify a pattern in one column based on Config type and time.
So, for each Config type, I like to mark True next to any "Start" Events that experience "Error(s)" between the "Start" and "End" Event.

See example table below and calculated column I am trying to write:

[image]

Your help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

If((Find('Error',UniqueConcatenate([Event]) OVER ([Config]))>0) and ([Event]='Start'),True,False)

Comment: Gaia, I think my problem statement was not clear enough, I apologize for this. I'd like to mark "True" next to the "Start" events that experience an error between that "Start" and an "End" Event.

Comment: that is what the calculated column does.